# Enable remote management on the Zyxel NBG-460N through the telnet utility

Tags: router, telnet

I was going through the remote management settings on my Zyxel NBG-460N router, making sure they were not available through the WAN port, when I stupidly without thinking **disabled** the WWW remote management. I can still login through telnet utility, but cannot find any documentation for that for the NBG-460N.

So, do anyone know how to enable the WWW remote management through the telnet utility for the NBG-460N or know of any CLI manual that is compatible?

If you know how to do this on other zyxel routers, please submit that as well, it could give some hints on doing it on the NBG-460N even if they don't work exactly the same, or if nothing else, it might help some other poor soul...

Comment: This is for a different router, but maybe it'll help http://mybroadband.co.za/vb/showthread.php?t=92791

Comment: You're not keen on resetting to factory defaults?

Comment: Maybe this http://www.zyxel.co.uk/web/support_faq_detail.php?faqID=192&pid=20040812093058

Comment: Ok ok ok, *this* one: http://www.zywall.com/support/knowledgebase1.php?indexFlagvalue=1023420662&level=3&upFlag=1021683378

Comment: Thanks, I really rather not reset the router, too many settings...
The info in second link worked, so just create a proper answer with the four lines (replace web with http) and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: whoops, was writing an answer just now, will edit with your solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OP stated these commands worked:

```
sys server load
sys server access http 0
sys server save

sys server disp
```

---

The `load` and `save` commands should enclose any `access` command.

Other formats for this command (based on the CLI version)

```
sys server access [ftp|telnet|web] [access type]

Set the server access type to be 0: ALL, 1: None, 2:LAN only, 3:WAN only
```

```
sys server access web 0
```

Also,

```
sys server access [telnet|ftp|ssh|http|https|icmp|snmp|dns]
       [lan|wan1|wan2|dmz|wlan] [on|off]
```

```
sys server access http lan on
```

Using `sys server disp` initially may give you a clue what the command should look like.  Refer to the CLI guides [here](http://www.zyxeltech.de/SNotep660hw/ci_cmd/p660hw_ci.htm) and [here](http://www.zyxel.com/web/support_download_list.php?indexflag=20060404175643).

Answer (score 1):

This is the only post related to the issue i was having so leaving this for future people. I have a Three 5G Broadband Router a Zyxel NR5103E 5G Hub i think. It’s CLI is very different but from looking.

1. SSH into the device
2. run `cfg mgmt_srv get`
3. run `cfg mgmt_srv edit --Index 1 --Mode LAN_ONLY`
4. run `exit`
5. SSH BACK IN
6. run `cfg mgmt_srv edit —-Index 2 —-Mode LAN_ONLY`

Your index may be different but just do it for HTTP (AND!!) HTTPS. Should now be able to access the Web Admin Pannel, if you’ve locked yourself out.